# How to use 'right(string, lenght)' in vb

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I'm new to vb and I'm trying to convert a vba macro in vb code.

I'm getting error on using "Right" for extracting a substring.

The error message (translated) is:
    'Public ReadOnly Property Right As Integer' has no parameters and the return type can not be indexed

When I try using 'right' Intellisense says me (translated):
    'Right() As Integer' get the distance in pixels between the right edge of the control and the left edge of the client area of the container (maybe the form?)

looking the web I found this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.strings.right%28v=vs.110%29.aspx
where there is this code:

```
'Declaration
Public Shared Function Right ( _
str As String, _
Length As Integer _
) As String
```

I made many attempts but I could not figure out where to place the statement or if I need to activate any reference

Where I'm wrong?

Update:
The not working code is simple:

```
MySubString = Trim(Right(MyString, 6))
```

Comment: Please post the code where this Right method is called

Comment: `Strings.Right(MyString, 6)`

Comment: Alternative, more .NET-way of doing this:  `MySubstring = MySubstring.Substring(MySubstring.Length - 6).Trim()`   I believe `Strings.Right` is a hold-over from the pre .NET days.

Comment: Just to complete the suggestion from @JoshPart Your code fails because the compiler thinks you are using the Right property of the current form (Me), If you really want to work with NET I strongly suggest to learn the NET way of doing things.

Comment: @Tim Thanks for alternative; @ Steve I'm "traslating" a vba project and it's my first approach to vb ... I have a lot to learn about it